Gradle Build Failure in Flutter Project with Error: "Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available"
I’m encountering a build issue in my Flutter project, which you can find here: Complete Food Delivery App Flutter. When trying to build the project, I get the following error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':fluttertoast:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 40.4s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Thanks!
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Checked Gradle Configuration:
Deleted .gradle caches and updated the Gradle wrapper.
Updated Dependencies:
Checked for dependency conflicts and updated dependencies in pubspec.yaml.
Flutter and Dart Versions:
Upgraded to the latest versions.
I’m using Android Studio on Windows with Flutter version 3.22.3. If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any suggestions, I’d really appreciate your help!
